# C# XNA - Iterating through items and drawing them

Tags: c#, for-loop, xna

So here's my code:

```
// Variables
private SpriteFont font;
private Vector2 fontPos, fontOrigin;
private List<string> menuItems;

// LoadContent()
font = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("myFont");
fontPos = new Vector2(1920 / 2, 1080 / 2);
menuItems = new List<string>();
menuItems.Add("Single Player");
menuItems.Add("Multi Player");
menuItems.Add("Achievements");
menuItems.Add("Options");
menuItems.Add("Quit Game");

// Draw()
for (int i = 0; i < menuItems.Count; i++)
{
    Vector2 fontOrigin = Game.gameFontLarge.MeasureString(menuItems[i]) / 2;
    spriteBatch.DrawString(Game.gameFontLarge, menuItems[i], new Vector2(ScreenManager.Instance.Dimensions.X / 2, ScreenManager.Instance.Dimensions.Y / 2), Game.NoTint, 0.0f, fontOrigin, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0.0f);
}
```

So far this code draws everything but all of the texts are drawn over each other on the same coordinates, the center of the screen. How to make each of the strings in the list draw below the previous one, like `24` pixels below the predecessor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, when you draw your strings, you can simply add a fixed pixel amount to each string's `y` value based on its index.

So your line here:

```
spriteBatch.DrawString( . . . , new Vector2(ScreenManager.Instance.Dimensions.X / 2, ScreenManager.Instance.Dimensions.Y / 2), . . .);
```

Becomes more like the following:

```
spriteBatch.DrawString( . . . , new Vector2(ScreenManager.Instance.Dimensions.X / 2, (ScreenManager.Instance.Dimensions.Y / 2) + 24 * i), . . .);
```

Hopefully this solution works for you - I'm not entirely familiar with XNA, but this should be the general idea. If it gives you a type mismatch error you may need to cast `i` by using `(float)i` instead.

Comment: Thanks! It works without casting `i` to float. As I've been testing, `Vector2.Y` and `Vector2.X` are `float`s but I didn't have to cast the `2` in the division because floats can be divided/multiplied by integers (maybe not in all cases, but this exact case doesn't need a cast)..